# current date in app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

Im trying to create a log file using log4net.
I have it create a log file. But i can't get the name of the log file to be the current date.

I have tried this:

```
<file value="log\\$date.txt"/>
```

But this just leans me with a file called "$date.txt" in the log folder.
I would like the file to be named "25-04-2012.txt"

Anyone know the little trick to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, you should use a RollingFileAppender

> This example show how to configure the RollingFileAppender to roll log
>   files on a date period. This example will roll the log file every
>   minute! To change the rolling period adjust the DatePattern value. For
>   example, a date pattern of "yyyyMMdd" will roll every day. See
>   System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo for a list of available
>   patterns.

```
<appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logfile" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Date" />
    <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd-HHmm" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

[Documentation (search for rollingFileappender)](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
  <param name="File" value="C:\Akhila\logger\logger\bin\Debug\log-" />
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```